# How to send an HTTP GET using AT firmware over serial connection?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, esp8266, pubnub

So I am using the [Arduino Uno](http://www.amazon.in/Arduino-Uno-USB-Cable-Rees52-com/dp/B014YUY3RC?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=dbeffa83-d282-4a4a-852f-6b081b74b493) and the [ESP8266 module](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwj5uNfckbHVAhWHiY8KHUyqAMYYABADGgJzYg&ohost=www.google.co.in&cid=CAASE-RoB01GXf-LtTKUmHMqDCWVG4Y&sig=AOD64_15RydtWJaJs4Mzs0CQD4qPVUJ5cw&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjHh9LckbHVAhWHrY8KHSg0B0AQvhcIMg&adurl=). I am trying to get the module to send an HTTP get request using the AT serial firmware however I am not quite able to do so.  The project gets data from a sensor and sends it in real time using the Pubnub Service by posting the data to the pubnub rest API.

I have the function:

```
void sendSerialCommand(String cmd, int t) {
  int i=0;
  while(1) {
    Serial.println(cmd);
    client.println(cmd); 
    while(client.available()) {
      if(client.find("OK"))
     i=8;
    }
    delay(t);
    if(i>5)
      break;
    i++;
  }
  if(i==8)
    Serial.println("OK");
  else
    Serial.println("Error");
}
```

Using this function, I set up a connection with the server as :

```
 sendSerialCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",100);
  sendSerialCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"" + pubnubIP + "\",80",1000);   
  Serial.println("Established connection with DashBoard Servers.....");
```

Then I try:

```
sendSerialCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," + String(getRequestLength) + "," + "http://" + pubnubIP + "/publish/<publish-key>/<sub-key>/0/water/0/<data>", 1000);
```

(I have put in the values for the publish and sub key in the actual code.)

The `getRequestLength` is the length of the data to be sent.

When I run the code, the output says `wait.....` and the the connection just closes. Could anyone please tell me the correct Syntax or method of sending the data?

Comment: Your `delay(t)` statement before `if(i>5)` makes no sense at all.  The variable `i` is not going change during such a delay, so postponing the test accomplishes nothing but make the code slower than necessary.  Maybe a delay *after* sending a command might make some sense.  Did you study the [ESP8266 WiFi Module Quick Start Guide](http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf)?  Your code doesn't seem to follow the "Acting as a TCP Client" section (i.e. check for a `Linked` response).

Comment: `sendSerialCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," + String(getRequestLength) + "," + "http://" + pubnubIP + "/publish/<publish-key>/<sub-key>/0/water/0/<data>", 1000);` This is *not* how you send a HTTP GET request. It has an entirely different format. Look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm.